# Capture a video frame to a bitmap

Tags: .net, image, directx, capture

I'm using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video class to play a video file and I would like to capture some frame to a bitmap.

The only export feature of this class is the RenderToTexture method and it accepts a Direct3D device as a parameter.

Someone know a simple way to obtain a System.Drawing.Bitmap from this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to capture a video frame using this API. I use DirectShow instead.